# Need to filter information received within email notification from SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I have enabled events on my S3 bucket so that whenever user places any file in the bucket, I receive an email notification via SNS. But the notification object has several fields such as eventVersion,requestParameters,responseElements etc. I am interested to have only detail of the user,name of the file placed in S3 bucket and not rest of the details. What option other than a lambda function can be used to filter information from the notification object?

Answer (score 1):

In the Amazon CloudWatch Event Rule configuration, you can use an input transformer to customize what is passed to the event target. [Here's a turorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html) that walks you through the process step by step. It uses a different example but it's similarly applicable to S3 events.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis for your reply. Having some difficulty in figuring out event pattern but otherwise it serves my purpose.